# Very weird jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I had code that *was* working properly on my site:

```
$("#usr").load("somepage.php",{var1:var1,var2:var2});
```

But ever since I changed some code in the navigation bar, jQuery has been acting really strangely. The first major problem was that this line:

```
var w = $(window).width();
```

returns the error: `object [global] has no method "width()"`

And that didn't seem to matter, as all elements on the page functioned with that error (as if it was still being executed, because elements were still being placed)...but then I came to the page that implemented the first line of code, and I ran into the following error:

```
Cannot call method "load()" of null
```

Sure enough, I checked the console, and $("#usr") returns null, but I can see the HTML line in the page with the inline id of `usr`.

This causes a problem because I need to load data from that page for the page to function properly. But it gets even stranger. I thought I would just try a plain post request and take the data and use `document.getElementById("usr").innerHTML = ...` as a substitute, but I get the following error from this line:

```
$.post("somepage.php",{var1:var1,var2:var2},function(data){
    document.getElementById("usr").innerHTML = data;
});
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function $(el){if(!el)return null;if(el.htmlElement)return Garbage.collect(el);if([window,document].contains(el))return el;var type=$type(el);if(type=='string'){el=document.getElementById(el);type=(el)?'element':false}if(type!='element')return null;if(el.htmlElement)return Garbage.collect(el);if(['object','embed'].contains(el.tagName.toLowerCase()))return el;$extend(el,Element.prototype);el.htmlElement=function(){};return Garbage.collect(el)} has no method 'post'
```

What the heck is going on with jQuery?

**I'm importing 1.8.2 from googleapis**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sounds a *lot* like you're loading Prototype or MooTools or something as well as jQuery, and so Prototype/MooTools/whatever is taking over the `$` symbol.

If that's what's going on, and you need the other library, you can use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict). Then you either use the symbol `jQuery` instead of `$` for your jQuery stuff, or you put all of your jQuery code into a function that you pass into `jQuery.noConflict` and accept `$` as an argument, like so:

```
// Out here, $ !== jQuery
jQuery.noConflict(function($) {
    // In here, $ === jQuery
});
```

Or you can just do it yourself:

```
// Out here, $ !== jQuery
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    // In here, $ === jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

[`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) also passes the jQuery object into the function, if you're already using `ready`.

Comment: @David have a look at `jQuery.noConflict`.

Comment: replacing `$` with `jQuery` worked no problem! Thanks! I'll accept it when it lets me ;)

Comment: @David: IMO, the only *real* solution is to *not* load multiple DOM manipulation libraries.

Comment: Well as it turns out, the navbar edit I made required `MooTools` ugh.

Comment: @David: Just remake it in jQuery, or redo your other code in MooTools. You're loading lots of overlapping functionality.