# $.post() not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery, .post

This is my code

```
var citylist = []; 
var index = 0; 
var url = "http://test.com/index.php"; 
var posting = $.post( url, { keystring: ""});
posting.done(function( data ) { 
  $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
     console.log(data);
     $.each(data, function(key, value) {
       citylist[index] = value;
       index++;
});
    if (index > 0) {
      $( "#destination_to" ).autocomplete({source: citylist});
    }
});
```

but I'm getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   Object function (e,l){return document.id(e,l,this.document);
>   } has no method 'post'

but the same method works fine for my previous project....can anyone tel wat shud be done??

Comment: It seems there is a  _$_ conflict in your page, try using `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: is jQuery even included properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Very weird jQuery error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708465/very-weird-jquery-error)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've not included jQuery or there is a conflict. Make sure your including jQuery  to your project and that there is no other library using the `$` namespace or set jQuery to run in `noConflict` mode.